# Sencha Touch app appears blank in browser both in Visual studio and Android emulator

Tags: sencha-touch

I just started using Sencha Touch and download its Free Commercial Version. I was trying the following sample in Visual studio, but I got the Sencha Touch app appears blank in browser. I tried in Safari (Version 5.1.7) and also in Chrome(Version 23). [Also I could able to see the example provided with the downloaded Sencha framework in safari, but not in Chrome).
The same application I tried in Android using the IDE eclipse. But there also the android emulator shows nothing.

Please help me to find out the issue.

Code:-

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- !CSS -->
    <link href="/content/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- !JS -->
    <script src="/content/js/sencha-touch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.setup({
            onReady: function () {
                // create the root panel
                new Ext.Panel({
                    fullscreen: true,
                    html: "Sencha Touch is ready!"
                });
            }
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I think your app is not getting initialized, check the examples provided with the Sencha SDK, try to add them in your project and run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the getting started documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started).

You are going to be using Visual Studio as a text editor, which is great but the [Architect](http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/) product might help you get going faster, i think there is a free version.

If you are still having issues the error in the "console" of the browser will help with other errors you might be having.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the index.html file as the Startup page?

On VS solution explorer, right-click the index.html file, then select Set As Start Page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio then u r obviously using IIS server on Windows. 
To get this working just add a new  MIME type "JSON" with extension .json to your we server. IIS  by default does not handle json mime type.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use (when debug) **Google Chrome** and won't work in <s>IE or Firefox</s>.

If you launch in Google Chrome then you'll see the results.